# Interaction range of fundamental forces at a unification energies

Tags: grand-unification, unified-theories

At low energies, all fundamental forces have different coupling constants as well as an interaction ranges.  As one know, at a some high energy (GUT energy $10^{14}$ GeV), all the coupling constants of fundamental forces (except gravity) are reduced to the same value $\alpha_{GUT} =1/40$.  What happens with the range of interaction?  It will be different, or it will be the same for all forces.  What value will it has?